# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, mybatis

I have problems with：

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'itemsController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.hdx.ssm.service.ItemsService com.hdx.ssm.controller.ItemsController.itemsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.hdx.ssm.service.ItemsService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is ItemsController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/items")
public class ItemsController {
    @Autowired
    private ItemsService itemsService;
```

and ItemsService:

```
  public interface ItemsService {
```

Implementation class：

```
public class ItemsServiceImpl implements ItemsService {
   @Autowired
   private ItemsMapperCustom itemsMapperCustom;
    @Autowired
    private ItemsMapper itemsMapper;
```

And some setting spring-mvc.xml:

```
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.hdx.ssm.controller"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" />
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>


    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"/> 
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Is ItemsServiceImpl  marked With `@Component` or `@Service`? Also `component-scan` should include path to service class .

Comment: I have modified it .Thanks for you answer！@Rohan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `@Service` as shown below to your `ItemsServiceImpl` in order to Spring container to know that it is a Spring managed bean:

```
@Service
public class ItemsServiceImpl implements ItemsService {
    @Autowired
   private ItemsMapperCustom itemsMapperCustom;
    @Autowired
    private ItemsMapper itemsMapper;

   //other code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer!@javaguy